# Angular 6 ng-serve don´t show dynamic images until restart

Tags: angular, image, angular-cli, assets

I can´t show images added dynamically on "/assets/images/" folder. But when i restart the server, the images already show.

I'm uploading images from my API server (script) to assets angular folder. Also i tried to upload files to server folder (api) but i cant access to the directory on ng-serve.

I'm using Angular CLI & Angular 6.

Comment: have u got any solution? even i am facing same issue.

Comment: @Vishnu not really, i just put it in assets folder, i need to check on hosting, but, i want to try using symbolic link from root folder to assets folder. I you find the issue, please, ask to me